# Installing gulp plugins locally vs globally

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, npm, gulp

I am pretty new to Gulp and I've got a question: should I install gulp plugins (such as gulp-sass or gulp-imagemin) locally or globally? In examples around the web people mostly do it locally (with `--save-dev` option). As I understand, by doing so the modules are stored in the local `node_modules` folder, added in the local `package.json` as devDependencies and can be referenced to in the local gulpfile.js via `require()`. So, if I need to install the same modules for another project I work on, it may be accomplished by copying `package.json` to a new project's folder and typing in `npm install` in a command line tool (after getting to the project's folder). Fine.

But what if I, as a regular gulp user, don't have plans to upload and share my stuff on the npm space and not interested in maintaining devDependencies, can I in this case just install gulp plugins globally like `npm install -g gulp-sass`? Will they be found through a global path in my system? Is it an option on the whole, if I don't want to bother myself to copy `package.json`, run `npm install` every time I create a new project or have multiple copies of the same modules scattered around on my disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plugins that you are using via gulp, what you have to do is install them locally to the project. Although you have to install gulp itself globally and locally, to run the file and then for the project to pick up the gulp based commands and functions.

The reason you should install the plugins via `npm` locally is so that it is specific to the project, for example if you then went to upload this project to your server or host on github then you would have to then go and have to globally install all of your packages again. If they are saved, they exist in your `packages.json`, this is so that when you go to run `npm install` to install all the packages for said project npm knows what to install.

If I can further clarify anything let me know.

Comment: yeah, I am getting your point, but I use sass, minifiers etc. generally in every project - they are not that specific and it would be greate to install them once and for all globally to use on every project on my PC. I have no plans to share my stuff with others and what is typically gets uploaded it is just plugins' results like '*.min.css' files.

Comment: Unfortunately `npm install -global` doesn't look for modules in the global directory. You can kind of fix this with changing your NODE_PATH environment variable. In Linux this will be: `export NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules` (or wherever your global directory is) source: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders

Comment: But not really advised. npm modules are usually quite small anyway.

Comment: so, you say that if a plugin (lets say gulp-sass) is installed globally it cannot be referenced by default via `require()` in a local gulpfile.js and calling `.pipe(sass())` will result in an error?

Comment: Yes, unless you have configured your `NODE_PATH` correctly, or its installed locally. @curveball

Comment: Ok, then it makes sense. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

A kind of "global install" for the typical case OP explained, could be to have a folder where you put your package.json with every dependencies you need for each of your projects, and run `npm install` from there.
And put here also your gulpfiles for each project (you could named them as you want), like gulpfile-project1.js, conf-project2.js... whatever.

Of course adjust your paths in those files accordingly.
And from this directory, run gulp using the -f flag:

```
gulp -f gulpfile-project1.js
```

So you end with this kind of scaffolding :

```
my_dev_directory
  - project1
    - dev
      - main.less
      - main.js
    - www
      - main.css
      - main.js
  - gulp
    - node_modules
    - package.json
    - package-lock.json
    - gulpfile-project1.js
```

In your gulpfiles, start to declare a const with the base path of your project to ease all path declarations, like:

```
const path_dev = '../project1/dev';
const path_www = '../project1/www';
```

This way you have only one node_modules directory installed on your disk and your projects directories contain only public files you want to upload, no dev files.

Of course one of the main drawback is that you share the same module version with all your projects, but it answered to OP's need and even if it's not recommended, not the "proper way to do", you are free to do as you want with your dev tools :)